# MySQL 5.5.24-log Update query join

Tags: mysql

In the database **`MySQL version 5.5.24-log`** I have two tables **`tbl_t1`** and **`tbl_t2`**.

This tables have in common the key **`area`**.

This is so true because if try this join query the output is correct:

```
mysql> SELECT
    areat2,
    areat1,
    nameareat1,
    monthareat2
FROM
    tbl_t1 t1
JOIN tbl_t2 t2 ON t1.areat1 = t2.areat2
WHERE
    monthareat2 = '2014-08'
GROUP BY
    t1.areat1
ORDER BY
    t1.nameareat1 ASC;
+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+
| areat2 | areat1 | nameareat1            | monthareat2 |
+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+
| XX4M   | XX4M   | AREA AAAAAA           | 2014-08     |
| XX5M   | XX5M   | AREA BBBBBB           | 2014-08     |
| XX4N   | XX4N   | AREA CCCCCC           | 2014-08     |
| XX1M   | XX1M   | AREA DDDDDD           | 2014-08     |
+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+
4 rows in set
```

Now I need update the field **`valid`** in table **`tbl_t1`** when the keys area of two tables are presents.

I have tried this solution, but I have error.

```
UPDATE tbl_t1 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
    areat2,
    areat1,
    nameareat1,
    monthareat2
    FROM
        tbl_t1 t1
    JOIN tbl_t2 t2 ON t1.areat1 = t2.areat2
    WHERE
        monthareat2 = '2014-08'
    GROUP BY
        t1.areat1
) AS t2 ON t1.areat1 = t2.areat2
SET t1.valid = 1;

[Err] 1060 - Duplicate column name 'areat1'
```

Can you explain how do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which query gives you these error message? show the table create statements of both tables.

Comment: The error is in the update query

Comment: There is no column with name `area`so the message can not be from it.

Comment: Im sorry, error in the copy/paste. I have correct the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use diferend aliases in your inner and outer query:

```
UPDATE tbl_t1 t3
JOIN (
    SELECT
    areat2,
    areat1,
    nameareat1,
    monthareat2
    FROM
        tbl_t1 t1
    JOIN tbl_t2 t2 ON t1.areat1 = t2.areat2
    WHERE
        monthareat2 = '2014-08'
    GROUP BY
        t1.areat1
) AS t4 ON t3.areat1 = t4.areat2
SET t3.valid = 1;
```